# How to update files in TFS Git Repository via build step?

Tags: git, command-line, tfs, build

[image]
As you can see, the TFS build is already connected to the git repo, Development.Services.

What I want to do is run a powershell script to retrieve some templates from an API to the $(build.sourcesDirectory) and then run a command to push them all to the Git Repo. I can handle the powershell part.

Except I have no clue what command to run for Git. When I click **Working Folder** in Advanced for Command Line, this pops up. I feel really close, but I need some direction on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Environment**: TFS 2015.3.

**Note**:

1. Instead of copying the templates to the $(build.sourcesDirectory), you can copy them to your local repo directory. Then specify the Working Folder to the local repo directory in all Command Lines tasks.
2. Run the build agent with an account that can push commits to TFS.
3. Make sure you have install Git on your build agent machine.

**Steps to achieve what you want**:

1. Run `git add <filename> command`:

[image]

2. Run `git commit -m "Commit message"`:

[image]

3. Run `git push origin master`:

[image]